# Android Include File Equivalent

Tags: java, android

I have a menu that I want to implement on multiple activities. If I change the menu I don't want to have to update these everytime in every place

```
onCreateOptionsMenu()
```

or

```
onOptionsItemSelected()
```

Is there a way to include these sections in an activity and link it to a single file to edit the menu?

Comment: This question demonstrates a fundamental lack of understanding in how Java works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option #1: Create your own subclass of `Activity`, implement those methods there, then extend your custom subclass for your actual activities.

Option #2: Create static methods someplace that implement the logic contained in those methods. Have each of your activities delegate to the static methods. This is a bit more work, but it still consolidates the real business logic, and you don't have to worry about any inheritance issues.